# Is this retirement wish appropriate to a senior lady?

Tags: expressions, politeness

A retirement wish on retirement card from an new employee to a senior lady that does not have a lot of connection at work. Does it look appropriate?

> All the best for your amazing retirement! Enjoy the new chapter in life, enjoy the years ahead!

The background is:
a guy's words to a senior lady;
a new employee to a lady that does not have a lot of connection at work.

my concerns were:
not to be over excited;
not to be rude;
and be polite and natural.

Does it look appropriate?

Comment: We try not to answer simple "proofreading" questions here.  If you add more context to explain why you are uncertain about this sentence, and any research you have done already, we may be able to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds great to me: Friendly, cheerful, and sincere without leaving the false impression that you two were very close friends.

Comment: To understand why you are being downvoted, please read the site rules to understand [which questions should be closed, rather than answered.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  The person asking the question has not provided enough information for us to understand why this is confusing, so any answer would not address any underlying grammar or syntax questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful answer Lorel C. I was asking if the retirement wish appropriate under the background of: 1. a guy's words to a senior lady at work; 2. a new employee to a lady that do not have a lot of connection at work.  all I want were not to be over excited; not to be rude but polite. I thought the word " appropriate" concludes the above and did not realize that was consider as a proofreading.  I do apologize for the downvote you received.